# Sound quality recording question

Tags: sound

How do I know if a sound recording sounds clear or not(if what is being said can be understood)? I understand my sound recordings, but other people can't, they say i have bad recording quality since they can't understand what is being said. Is there any way to measure the clearness of a sound recording?

Comment: Please note that any knowledge about the content of a piece of information (this is, in essence, what a signal is) is used by the human brain. For example, visual cues can greatly enhance aural localisation (if you see something while listening to it you'll be able to localise it better and this is a great issue at 3D movies). This means that you may be able to understand your recordings because you are already aware of their content. This is not necessarily the case though since we don't know how other people reproduce your audio. It could be any part of the signal chain from rec to repro.

Answer (score 3):

In telecommunication networks one of the commonly used methods is Full Reference. This method uses an algorithm to evaluate speech samples by simulating the process of the human ear listening to reference audio files.

Next, they compare the samples to determine the audible difference. The data then undergoes a process, called the cognitive model, comparable to the way the human brain would process such data. A picture of overall voice quality is generated.

A more straightforward approach to speech quality testing is conducting listening sessions, resulting in subjective quality results.

A group of people listens to recordings under controlled settings. They’re then asked to provide normalized feedback (e.g. on a scale from 1 to 5). Responses are then aggregated into a single quality value, called Mean Opinion Score (MOS). Aggregation is necessary to avoid subject bias.